# rbenv install - executable host ruby is required

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I am trying to install ruby 2.2.0-dev using rbenv into my Ubuntu 13.10 development laptop. I have removed all previous ruby and gem installations. Now, when I try to install ruby I get the following error.

```
mark@Inspiron-1564:~/.rbenv$ rbenv install 2.2.0-dev
Cloning https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git...
Installing ruby-2.2.0-dev...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140119161217.4141
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140119161217.4141.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20140119161217.4141 ~/.rbenv
Cloning into 'ruby-2.2.0-dev'...
Checking connectivity... done
/tmp/ruby-build.20140119161217.4141/ruby-2.2.0-dev /tmp/ruby-build.20140119161217.4141 ~/.rbenv
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.; false -C ./tool get-config_files config.guess
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.; false -C ./tool get-config_files config.sub
configure: error: cannot run /bin/bash tool/config.sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `rbenv` without a native installation of `ruby` in the machine. You should install ubuntu's ruby (`sudo apt-get install ruby`) so rbenv will have a base version to work with. If you can run `ruby -v` then you're all set.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case but none of the many tutorials for installing rbenv made specific mention of it so I thought I would ask. I even saw some references that suggested a system install was undesirable.

Comment: I ran apt-get install ruby and then got the same error installing ruby with rbenv. [code]ruby -v[/code] now reports 1.8 and 1.9.1

Comment: Maybe you should check on http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/13.10, it does not say to have `ruby` installed. You might be missing some other library, but the error reads as if it can't find a ruby to run. Another thing, you might need to install `ruby-2.2.0` before installing the `-dev` version.

Comment: ruby-2.1.0 installs OK so I can't install 2.2.0-dev without another version of ruby installed. I still don't know if a native ruby needs to be installed.

Comment: Yes, this is a restriction for compilation that started in ruby 1.9: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206642

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

you need a non-dev version (i.e. `2.2.0`) installed (also using `rbenv`) before you can have the `dev` version.

---

As of `rbenv 1.0.0` you **don't** need to have `ruby` from the repository (e.g. using `apt-get`) installed on your machine to be have any `*-dev` version installed. **However**, it is required to have a non-dev version already installed (through `rbenv`) before installing any `*-dev` version.