# Error while building ruby trunk

Tags: ruby

I cloned the trunk branch from my fork of Ruby on GitHub and I am following the directions in the README to build ruby-trunk. Step #2 in the [How to compile and install](https://github.com/shishir127/ruby#how-to-compile-and-install) is

> If ./configure does not exist or is older than configure.in, run
> autoconf to (re)generate configure.

The configure file wasn't there in the repo so I ran autoconf. When I execute the generated configure file, I get an error

```
build git:(trunk) ../configure
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
configure: error: cannot run /bin/bash ../tool/config.sub
```

I use zsh so I thought that may have something to do with the problem. So I did a clean clone of the repo again and followed the same directions using bash but I still got the same error.

I did google this and all replies to this error said that I have to have ruby already installed to build ruby. But I already have several rubies installed on my system and I'm still getting this error each time. I use rbenv to manage the ruby versions.

Has anyone else faced this problem or does anyone else have any suggestions about what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rbenv install - executable host ruby is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214384/rbenv-install-executable-host-ruby-is-required)